# the validation set is used as the test set in top tier venue papers

Tags: validation, machine-learning, deep-learning, training-data

I have been checking some ICCV and CVPR papers and their codes, I have noticed that many a times the validation set is used as the test set, however as far as I am concerned, these sets should be different as the model being trained finetunes hyperparameters during the validation therefore the model will be biased if the same set is used for testing.

I saw this blog writing:

```
The validation set is used to evaluate a given model, but this is for frequent evaluation. We as machine learning engineers use this data to fine-tune the model hyperparameters. Hence the model occasionally sees this data, but never does it “Learn” from this. We(mostly humans, at-least as of 2017  ) use the validation set results and update higher level hyperparameters. So the validation set in a way affects a model, but indirectly.
```

So, it says that it is not good practice but it is common??

There is a paper that is recently published in my domain, on a dataset I work on, this dataset does not come with a validation set and the paper (and many other papers from that group that uses the same dataset) never mentions splitting a val dataset that is separate from the test dataset. It is also sort of difficult to do this as the dataset is rather small and it is hard to split them (because you need to do this at the actor in the videos level (leave one actor out) and there are not many actors.

So what is the consensus? I share the sentiment that it is not good practice but then how come many papers at top tier venues do this?